# How can i toggle a checkbox clicking a button outside the checkbox on angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox, toggle

I'm trying to make a list where the user can remove the selected items in two ways, clicking on the checkbox and clicking on a "-" to remove the item from the list. The problem is when i delete something clicking on - the checkbox wont toggle. My function: `

```
onChange(item: Selecionado){
    // console.log(id, isChecked)
    // console.log($event.target.value)
    const indexCdc = this.selecionados.findIndex(sele => sele.id === item.id)
    console.log(indexCdc)
    if (indexCdc !== -1){
      console.log(this.selecionados)
      console.log("entrou aqui")
      this.selecionados[this.selecionados.findIndex(e => e.id === item.id)].checked = false
      this.selecionados.splice(this.selecionados.findIndex(e => e.id === item.id),1)
      return
    }
    else{this.selecionados.push(item)}
```

`

`
My html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of listas">
        <td><input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(item)" [checked]="checked"/></td>
        <td>{{ item ["id"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item["nome"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item["idade" ]}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of selecionados">
        <td (click)="onChange(item)"> - </td>
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.nome }}</td>
    </tr>
```

When selecting the check box it will appear like this:
[Items selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrN1p.png)
So when i click on - i want the checkbox to untoggle like this:[The check  box should like as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh95v.png)
But when i click on the -, the item is removed from my array but the checkbox won't change.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'd suggest looking at how your binding to the value of the checkbox, rather than setting `[checked]` try using `[(ngModel)]`.